# WPF filtered dynamic menu

Tags: wpf

I'm working on getting a UserControl in WPF working that has a MenuItem populated with an ItemsSource, which creates a menu that goes n levels deep (although I'm just looking at TopMenuItem\Branches\Leaves right now).
The wrinkle I'm having trouble with is that I want to filter the leaves through a textbox embedded into the menu. If a branch has no leaves, it also gets filtered out. It looks like this at the moment :

[image: It looks like this at the moment]

I'm working with an ObservableCollection of IMenuTreeItem, which can contain branches (which in turn also has an ObservableCollection of IMenuTreeItem) or leaves.

```
public interface IMenuTreeItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MenuTreeLeaf : IMenuTreeItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid UID { get; set; }
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; }
    public Requirement Requirement { get; set; }

    public MenuTreeLeaf(string name, ObjectType type, Guid uID)
    {
        Type = type;
        Name = name;
        UID = uID;
    }
    public MenuTreeLeaf(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
public class MenuTreeBranch : IMenuTreeItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MenuTreeBranch(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

This is how I'm filtering. It very much feels like there's a better way.

```
            ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem> result = new ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem>(ItemsSource);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                if (result[i] is MenuTreeBranch currentBranch)
                {
                    if (currentBranch.Items != null)
                        currentBranch.Items = new ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem>(currentBranch.Items.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchField.ToLower())));
                }
            }
            result = new ObservableCollection<IMenuTreeItem>(result.Where(x => (x as MenuTreeBranch).Items.Count > 0));
            result.Insert(0, new MenuTreeLeaf("[Search]"));
            return result;
```

So my main problems are:

- When I've filtered, I can no longer unfilter. ItemsSource gets changed too. Could it be because I'm filtering in the ItemsSourceFiltered getter? I tried to clone, but eh, didn't change anything
- When I call OnPropertyChanged on ItemsSourceFiltered any time text changes in the textbox, the menu closes. The menu definitely shouldn't close while you're inputting text.

Any advice?

Comment: You need something like a private list of allitems. You could filter using a collectionview. There's an observablecollection ctor takes a list. So you could tolist() and new up an observablecollection passing that list.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a menu item class that exposes a recursive Filter string and a collection property that returns the filtered child items:

```
public class FilteredMenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    private string filter;

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return filter; }
        set
        {
            filter = value;

            foreach (var childItem in ChildItems)
            {
                childItem.Filter = filter;
            }

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Filter)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FilteredChildItems)));
        }
    }

    public List<FilteredMenuItem> ChildItems { get; set; } = new List<FilteredMenuItem>();

    public IEnumerable<FilteredMenuItem> FilteredChildItems
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter)
                ? ChildItems
                : ChildItems.Where(childItem => (bool)childItem.Name?.Contains(Filter)); }
    }
}
```

With a `RootItem` property in the view model like

```
public FilteredMenuItem RootItem { get; }
    = new FilteredMenuItem { Name = "Items" };
```

you may bind to it in XAML like this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RootItem}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                        Value="{Binding FilteredChildItems}"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <MenuItem/>
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```

While you populate the `ChildItems` property of each FilteredMenuItem, the view only shows the `FilteredChildItems` collection.

You may also notice that the above doesn't use `ObservableCollection` at all, since no items are added to or removed from any collection at runtime. You just have to make sure the item tree is populated before the view is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to restructure some since I need the Textbox as the first item in the Menu (like in my image), and leaves have to be a different class than the branches.
It fixes the problem that I couldn't unfilter, but it still closes the Menu whenever I type anything into the searchbox.

Comment: A menu isn't supposed to stay open when a different element gets input. Consider using a different control, perhaps a TreeView.

Comment: Even if the element is a MenuItem in the same menu, like the textbox? That is frustrating. I did see it in other tools in the past, which is why I got the idea.
If this isn't possible at all, I guess I really have to restructure my screen and possibly use a treeview.

Comment: Maybe something like this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711644/1136211

Comment: doesn't seem to apply here.
After some tests, the reason the menu closes is ItemsSource getting updated. If I leave the propertychange invoke out, the menu no longer closes. The interesting thing is that the menu also doesn't close when I delete characters. So essentially: Menu closes when list becomes smaller. Menu doesn't close when list becomes bigger.